# Can you fit arrows automatically to a plt text in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have some rectangles with text in it that are connected by directed edges, my code is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



plt.close()   

pos_rec={0: (0,0), 1:(20,30), 2:(50,10)}

text_rec={0:"ShortText", 1:"A Bit Longer", 2:"A Much Longer Text" }

ax = plt.gca()

edges=((0,1),(1,2),(2,0))


for i in pos_rec:
        plt.text(pos_rec[i][0],pos_rec[i][1],s=text_rec[i],fontsize=15,fontweight="bold", bbox=dict(boxstyle='round',facecolor='red', edgecolor='r', pad=0.7),horizontalalignment='center')


for edge in edges:
    ax.annotate("",xy=pos_rec[edge[0]], xytext=pos_rec[edge[1]],
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<|-,head_length=1,head_width=0.5",lw=2, shrinkA=18, shrinkB=20, color='b')
    )
    


 
plt.show()
```

Now the problem is that the edges are stuck in the box which of course does not look very beautiful - I could solve this by drawing the boxes after the edges, so the overlapping is hidden by the box but then the edge arrows might disappear;

With the option shrinkA and shrinkB I can adjust the arrow lenth at the starting and end point, so theoretically I can manually fix it in such a way that the arrows indeed end at the rectangle. The problem is that those arrows are stuck in the box in different depths - moreover, depending on what scale I choose, it is possible that the arrows are deeper or less deep inside those boxes;

The output of the code for different scales can be seen here:

[image: Result with different scale(1)][image: Result with different scale(2)]

So the very natural question for me is: Is it somehow possible to let those edges end directly at the border of those rectangles?

Can this be done even independent of the scaling,i.e. no matter if I zoom in or outside, the edges always end right at the border of the rectangle?

And what if those edges are curved as in the example below?

[image: Result with Curved Edges]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_tighbbox()` to get bounding box, and plot arrows according to the `.bounds`. You are also recomended to read [transformations tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) of matplotlib for more information.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

t1 = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'text',  bbox=dict(boxstyle='round',facecolor='red', edgecolor='r'))
t2 = ax.text(0.3, 0.3, 'text',  bbox=dict(boxstyle='round',facecolor='red', edgecolor='r'))


x1, y1, w1, h1 = t1.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer()).bounds
x2, y2, w2, h2 = t2.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer()).bounds
plt.annotate(' ', (x2+w2, y2+h2),(x1, y1), xycoords='figure pixels', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<|-,head_length=1,head_width=0.5",lw=2, color='b'))
```

[image]